# Find MSI install package for pre-installed application?

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer, registry

Here's what I'm looking to do:

I'd like to **perform an application install on a remote machine**; as a part of that process, before I install the new version, I want to **check that machine's registry for a pre-existing version** of the same application.

If that machine has an existing instance of the application already installed, I want to **find the MSI used to install it**, so I can backup the MSI and perform a 'rollback' if necessary. From what I understand, Windows creates a copy of these MSIs and places them in some temp folder with a random name somewhere so that it can use it for uninstalls.

How might I find this location?
(Also, suggestions on how to check the registry values cross-network would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, you don't have to find the exact MSI package. In order to uninstall a product, it is enough to know its product code and run `msiexec /x {PRODUCT-CODE-GUID-HERE}`. And product codes can be found under Uninstall registry key (typically, `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`).

Comment: Yep: this is basically what I found after searching. I wanted to find the MSI cached by the OS at "C:\Windows\Installer\<junk>.msi" which I was able to find at "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\<GUID>\InstallProperties" in the LocalPackage value. (As found on my Windows Vista machine.)

Comment: @Dave Yeah, and that <GUID> in the registry path you provided is the munged Product Code GUID. Just in case someone is trying to automate the process of obtaining the cached MSI from the product code. Here is a link providing info on what a munged GUID is: http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/guid-converter